# D how to mark everything __gshared?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, d, dmd

Is there any way to mark all objects `__gshared` with DMD? I am working on a game engine where pretty much everything needs to be shared between threads, and spamming `__gshared` or `shared` everywhere doesn't cut it.

For everyone wanting me not to do this: Critical sections will be minimal and reduced to checking if an enum is set to Loaded or not (mutexed of course). So concurrency won't gain me anything.

Comment: `__gshared:` before the first declaration doesn't work?

Comment: I have too many variables that need to be shared, I don't want to see `__gshared` everywhere.

Comment: Note the colon. Any qualifier/attribute can be applied via "attr:" and "attr { }" syntax, than it is applied to _all_ declarations in scope / after the colon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can put all the variables in a block and declare that shared

```
__gshared{
   SharedClass instance;
   //...
}
```

also note that all fields in a shared class or struct are shared

I should however note that this inconvenience is by design and an encouragement to restructure your data to minimize the shared stuff

Comment: It's not that easy to minimize it when one wants to load pretty much every resource in another thread. Thank you anyway, and sorry for not seeing the colon in your first response.

Comment: another way is to cast to and from share as you communicate between threads

Answer (score -1):

__gshared tells garbage collector that resource is may be used within external code, so you will need manually alloc/dealloc it(and so you can access the same resource in any thread), shared on the other hand is for actual multi-thread sharing.

though i may be wrong on some details, the actual idea is that

Comment: __gshared does not break resource allocation or the garbage collector. It simply puts the variable back into global storage.